# Android table specifications for google play store

Tags: android-manifest, android

I'm developing an app for both phones over 2.2 and tablets. But after i published the apk on the google play store, tablets are not recognized (any tablets). Here are information from the manifest regarding the permission:

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.adonissoft.urbanhero.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

...



 <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

...
```

Also i have resources for large/xlarge/sw600dp/sw720dp (layouts, drawables, values)

Is there something missing ?

Also if you think more info is needed please tell ... and i will try to provide

Comment: IDK I don't have tablet.  Did you add tablet images?

Comment: yes ... i don't think missing layout/img etc is the problem ... i think that is something with the xml design cuz google play states this problem: Your Production APK needs to meet the following criteria: Uses available screen space on tablets. Learn more. But i tested on simulator and real tablet ... and the design looks just fine : / ... i think i should tweak something but i'm stuck on what to modify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that only tablets are filtered out?

Google Play filters applications based on explicit and implicit feature requirements. Implicit feature requirements [are derived from requested permissions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#permissions). For example, your manifest implies GPS requirement.

If your app doesn't really need GPS, you need to disable the filter explicitly

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"
    android:required="false" />
```

There are also other implicit requirements, for example, if you force portrait orientation for any of yours activity, Play Store will filter devices by the implicit **android.hardware.screen.portrait** requirement, which can be also explicitly disabled

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.screen.portrait"
    android:required="false" />
```

Comment: as the app needs to have gps and to be in portrait does requirments have to be there, but i don't think thats the problem. There is something in the design i think, or something missing since this is the error i get from google play store:  Your Production APK needs to meet the following criteria:
Uses available screen space on tablets. Learn more